# How to Build Xalan-C with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: xalan

How to build `Xalan-C1.1` with Visual Studio 2012 on Windows. Is it possible?

Tried opening the  xalan_c-1.11-src\xalan-c-1.11\c\Projects\Win32\VC10\Xalan.sln with VS 2012, it updated all the files to compile with VS 2012. Then tried **Build** and got the following error :

**ERROR : The project file '' has been renamed or is no longer in the solution.**

Do I need to change anything?

Thanks.